# django dynamic add form fields

Tags: django, forms, dynamic

Based on [this](http://stellarchariot.com/blog/2011/02/dynamically-add-form-to-formset-using-javascript-and-django/) i want to write a dynamic template, where i can dynamicly add forms with choosen width.

Models:

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
    SEC = 'section'
    DIV = 'div'
    SECCHOICES = (
        (SEC, "Section"),
        (DIV, "Div"),
    )
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SECCHOICES, default=SEC)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class TodoItem(models.Model):
    COL16 = '16'
    COL25 = '25'
    COL33 = '33'
    COL50 = '50'
    COL66 = '66'
    COL75 = '75'
    COL100 = '100'
    CHOICES = (
        (COL16, "16%"),
        (COL25, "25%"),
        (COL33, "33%"),
        (COL50, "50%"),
        (COL66, "66%"),
        (COL75, "75%"),
        (COL100, "100%"),
    )
    width = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CHOICES, default=COL100)
    list = models.ForeignKey(TodoList)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name + " (" + str(self.list) + ")"
```

View:

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = TodoItem.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <{{ post.list.tag }}>
        <div class="column{{ post.width }}" >
        </div>
    </{{ post.list.tag }}>
{% endfor %}
```

Output is:

Section: col, Section: col, Section: col, Section: col

And i wish:

Section: col, col, col, col

Happy about any Ideas, Sorry if something is too stupid – im very new to django/python

Comment: Have you checked out [the django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) package?

Comment: no havent yet i will go through it ty!

Comment: for sure my bad but can't install this… does it work with django 1.7.1? only getting one error after another

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by doing this only?

```
<{{ post.list.tag }}>
{% for post in posts %}
   <div class="column{{ post.width }}" >
   </div>
{% endfor %}
</{{ post.list.tag }}>
```